# How to hide @ for Crystal report formula in Graph legends

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a requirement to show the text of the Bar chart Legend in Finnish. Currently, it is in English. I renamed the formula and modified the Chart Expert -> Data -> Show values{s) to use the latest formula.

Now it is changed to Finnish text as per requirement. This value is shown in the below image. How to hide @ from the graph while running the report.

[image]

Comment: Is the @ symbol showing when you execute the report?  Normally the @ symbol is used to denote that the field name is a Formula Field.  In design view you see the name of the field, but at runtime it should change to the value of the field.

Comment: In the Graph legend, it is showing with @ in runtime also. Is it possible to change it like DisplayString in run time